# Como hacer para que no se borren los archivos de mi arraylist cuando los guardo en un fichero?

Tags: java

Estoy guardando objetos dentro de un arraylist llamado "listaDeArticulos", este arraylist luego de guardar sus articulos dentro, lo guardo en un .txt llamado "articulos.dat". Al hacer esto, el arraylist se vacia por completo y no tengo la oportunidad de, por ejemplo, modificar sus objetos o eliminarlos, etc etc.

Como podría hacer, para qué se carguen los datos de articulos.dat otra vez en un arraylist y asi poder modificarlos para luego volver a guardarlos ya modificados?

Codigo con el que escribo el arraylist en el .txt

```
FileWriter fout = new FileWriter(rutaArticulos, true);
                    BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(fout);

                    for (articulos articulos : listaDeArticulos) {
                        output.write("\r\n" + "Numero: " + articulos.getNumero() + "\r\n" + "Nombre: "
                                + articulos.getNombre() + "\r\n" + "Codigo: " + articulos.getCodigo() + "\r\n"
                                + "Precio: $" + articulos.getPrecio() + "\r\n" + "Stock: " + articulos.getStock()
                                + "\r\n---\r\n");
                    }

                    output.close();
                    fout.close();
```

> case 1 Agregar articulos:

```
case 1:
                archi2.createFile(rutaArticulos);
                AgregarArticulos(listaDeArticulos);
                do {

                    try {

                        System.out.println("n1-Guardar\nOtro numero para salir sin guardar.");
                        Scanner asd = new Scanner(System.in);
                        asd1 = asd.nextInt();
                        optiontrue = true;
                    } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
                        System.out.println("¡Solo puedes insertar números!");
                        optiontrue = false;
                    }
                } while (asd1 < 0 || optiontrue == false);
                if (asd1 == 1) {
                    FileWriter fout = new FileWriter(rutaArticulos, true);
                    BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(fout);

                    for (articulos articulos : listaDeArticulos) {
                        output.write("\r\n" + "Numero: " + articulos.getNumero() + "\r\n" + "Nombre: "
                                + articulos.getNombre() + "\r\n" + "Codigo: " + articulos.getCodigo() + "\r\n"
                                + "Precio: $" + articulos.getPrecio() + "\r\n" + "Stock: " + articulos.getStock()
                                + "\r\n---\r\n");
                    }

                    output.close();
                    fout.close();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("El archivo no se guardó y ha salido exitosamente.");
                }
```

> Funcion AgregarArticulo

```
public void AgregarArticulos(List<articulos> listaDeArticulos) throws IOException {
    Scanner reemplazable = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        boolean boolar = true;

        articulos art = new articulos();

        // numero
        do {
            try {
                System.out.println("Numero: ");

                Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
                newnum = num.nextInt();
                boolar = true;
            } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
                System.out.println("¡Valor no agregado! Solo puedes insertar números positivos. ");
                boolar = false;
            }
        }

        while (newnum < 0 || boolar == false);

        art.setNumero(newnum);

        // nombre
        System.out.println("Producto: ");

        Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in);
        String newname = name.nextLine();

        art.setNombre(newname);

        // codigo
        do {
            try {

                System.out.println("Codigo: ");

                Scanner codigo = new Scanner(System.in);
                newcodigo = codigo.nextInt();
                boolar = true;

            } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
                System.out.println("¡Codigo no agregado! Solo puedes insertar números positivos. ");
                boolar = false;
            }
        } while (newcodigo < 0 || boolar == false);
        art.setCodigo(newcodigo);

        // precio
        do {
            try {

                System.out.println("Precio: ");

                Scanner codigo = new Scanner(System.in);
                newprecio = codigo.nextInt();
                boolar = true;

            } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
                System.out.println("¡Precio no agregado! Solo puedes insertar números positivos. ");
                boolar = false;
            }
        } while (newprecio < 0 || boolar == false);
        art.setPrecio(newprecio);

        // stock

        do {
            try {

                System.out.println("Stock: ");

                Scanner codigo = new Scanner(System.in);
                newstock = codigo.nextInt();
                boolar = true;

            } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
                System.out.println("¡Codigo no agregado! Solo puedes insertar números positivos. ");
                boolar = false;
            }
        } while (newstock < 0 || boolar == false);
        art.setStock(newstock);

        listaDeArticulos.add(art);          
        
        do {

            try {

                System.out.println("\n1-Continuar Agregando\n2-Volver al menu anterior");
                Scanner sc3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                preg = sc3.nextInt();
                optioncont = true;
            } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
                System.out.println("¡Solo puedes insertar números!");
                optioncont = false;
            }
        } while (preg < 0 || optioncont == false);

    } while (preg == 1);
}
```

Aqui en AgregarArticulo voy seteando los atributos de mi objeto con los datos que me de el usuario y al final lo agrego en la list listaDeArticulos, luego pregunto si quiere guardarlo y si ponen que si, ahi es donde se ejecuta el codigo que lo escribe en el txt tengo entendido.

si yo luego de esto vuelvo al menu principal y le doy al case 3 que es "modificar articulos"donde tengo el siguiente código:

> case 3: "Modificar Articulos"

```
case 3:
                mostrarArticulos(listaDeArticulos);
                
                System.out.println("Que articulo desea modificar? ");
                Scanner artscan = new Scanner(System.in);
                artselec=artscan.nextInt();
            
                System.out.println("Se eligio:\n");
                System.out.println(listaDeArticulos.get(artselec));
```

Aqui en mostrarArticulos muestro los datos guardados en el txt y pregunto que articulo desea modificar para que el usuario pueda elegir alguno mediante un numero y luego quiero mostrarlo pero me tira el error de IndexOutOfBoundsException sin importar la posicion que elija.

He probado decirle que no guarde y meterle un system.out.println(listaDeArticulos) luego de decirle que no, y me muestra el arraylist con todos sus datos correctos.

No logro encontrar donde está el error :(

Comment: En teoría con ese código no estas quitando elementos de la lista, solo lo estas recorriendo. ¿Cómo sabes que esta vacío?

Comment: Antes de ejecutar ese codigo imprimo la list en pantalla y estan todos los objetos dentro, luego de guardarlo en txt con el codigo de arriba,  vuelvo a imprimirlo en pantalla y se imprime [], tambien, si quiero imprimir un index determinado del arraylist me tire el error index bounds exepcion

Comment: Puedes añadir más código? La función completa, para ver donde haces los print

Comment: @DarkFrostnight ahí agregue todo el código, gracias por ayudarme

Comment: Tu función AgregarArticulo debe retornar la lista de artículos, por que el valor que pasas y cuando añades el item se queda en la función AgregarArticulo, debes retornarlo para poder escribirlo posteriormente

Comment: Le cambio el void por un List<articulos> y debajo antes de que cierre le coloco return listaDeArticulos entonces? o como seria?

Comment: Si, y el resultado de la función lo asignas a una variable, `listaDeArticulos = AgregarArticulos(listaDeArticulos);`

Comment: En donde coloco esa linea?

Comment: Te dejo los cambios como una respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo en tu código, no estas trabajando con la lista que estas llenando en la función **AgregarArticulo**, entonces, es necesario modificar tu función **AgregarArticulo**. retornado la lista con los datos que agregas en la función.

El código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

Función **AgregarArticulo**:

```
public List<articulos> AgregarArticulos(List<articulos> listaDeArticulos) throws IOException {
    Scanner reemplazable = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        boolean boolar = true;

        articulos art = new articulos();

        // numero
        do {
            try {
                System.out.println("Numero: ");

                Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
                newnum = num.nextInt();
                boolar = true;
            } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
                System.out.println("¡Valor no agregado! Solo puedes insertar números positivos. ");
                boolar = false;
            }
        }

        while (newnum < 0 || boolar == false);

        art.setNumero(newnum);

        // nombre
        System.out.println("Producto: ");

        Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in);
        String newname = name.nextLine();

        art.setNombre(newname);

        // codigo
        do {
            try {

                System.out.println("Codigo: ");

                Scanner codigo = new Scanner(System.in);
                newcodigo = codigo.nextInt();
                boolar = true;

            } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
                System.out.println("¡Codigo no agregado! Solo puedes insertar números positivos. ");
                boolar = false;
            }
        } while (newcodigo < 0 || boolar == false);
        art.setCodigo(newcodigo);

        // precio
        do {
            try {

                System.out.println("Precio: ");

                Scanner codigo = new Scanner(System.in);
                newprecio = codigo.nextInt();
                boolar = true;

            } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
                System.out.println("¡Precio no agregado! Solo puedes insertar números positivos. ");
                boolar = false;
            }
        } while (newprecio < 0 || boolar == false);
        art.setPrecio(newprecio);

        // stock

        do {
            try {

                System.out.println("Stock: ");

                Scanner codigo = new Scanner(System.in);
                newstock = codigo.nextInt();
                boolar = true;

            } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
                System.out.println("¡Codigo no agregado! Solo puedes insertar números positivos. ");
                boolar = false;
            }
        } while (newstock < 0 || boolar == false);
        art.setStock(newstock);

        listaDeArticulos.add(art);          
        
        do {

            try {

                System.out.println("\n1-Continuar Agregando\n2-Volver al menu anterior");
                Scanner sc3 = new Scanner(System.in);
                preg = sc3.nextInt();
                optioncont = true;
            } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
                System.out.println("¡Solo puedes insertar números!");
                optioncont = false;
            }
        } while (preg < 0 || optioncont == false);

    } while (preg == 1);

    return listaDeArticulos;
}
```

Y en case1, debes remplazar la siguiente linea:

```
AgregarArticulos(listaDeArticulos);
```

por

```
listaDeArticulos = AgregarArticulos(listaDeArticulos);
```

Comment: Funciona correctamente si lo ejecuto una sola vez, es decir, si cargo articulos y luego voy a modificarlos, me imprime el arraylist correctamente con todos los articulos. Si ejecuto otra vez el codigo y voy directamente a modificar articulos para modificar los articulos del txt me imprime el array vacio. Estoy teniendo problemas otra vez :( Creo que deberia recuperar los archivos de "articulos.dat", meterlos en un arraylist y asi poder modificarlos, o qués estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Claro eso es por que lo estas trabajando en memoria, y responde a tu pregunta inicial, que era que el array se te muestra vacío, lo que comentas ahora es otra cosa, y es que al cargar el programa te lea el archivo y lo puedas trabajar nuevamente en memoria. Como recomendación, no puedes estar escribiendo y leyendo constantemente el archivo, es mejor leer una vez, trabajarlo en memoria y escribirlo cuando sea necesario.

Comment: Entiendo mucho mejor ahora, cual seria la mejor opcion para hacer un menu donde pueda cargar articulos, verlos, modificarlos y que a su vez estos se carguen en un txt y queden guardados al ejecutar otra vez el programa? Porque se me habia ocurrido esto y por lo que me explicas no es recomendable :)

Comment: por lo que yo veo, tu código esta bien, solo debes añadir una función que al arrancar el programa lea el archivo y lo meta en el array, el como lo haces, eso ya te toca a ti.

Por otra parte, debes añadir que se escriba el archivo cuando modificas el array, por que ya escribes el archivo cuando añades. Con eso debería ser suficiente.